# comma separated column in linq where clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

i have string of value like "4,3,8"

and i had comma separated column in table as below.

```
    ID   |  PrdID   |  cntrlIDs 
    1    |   1      |   4,8
    2    |   2      |   3
    3    |   3      |   3,4
    4    |   4      |   5,6
    5    |   5      |   10,14,18
```

i want only those records from above table which match in above mention string

eg.
1,2,3 this records will need in output because its match with the passing string of "4,3,8"

Note : i need this in entity framework LINQ Query.

```
string[] arrSearchFilter = "4,3,8".Split(',');
var query = (from prdtbl in ProductTables 
where prdtbl.cntrlIDs.Split(',').Any(x=> arrSearchFilter.Contains(x))
```

but its not working and i got below error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: you need to first get the data from your entities and then do the above statement. first do var myList =  (from prdtbl in ProductTables select prdtbl).tolist(); then query from myList as you did above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to Entities tries to convert query expressions to SQL. String.Split is not one of the supported methods. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738534(v=vs.100).aspx

Assuming you are unable to redesign the database structure, you have to bypass the SQL filter and obtain ALL records and then apply the filter. You can do this by using `ProductTables.ToList()` and then using this in second query with the string split, e.g.

```
string[] arrSearchFilter = "4,3,8".Split(',');
var products = ProductTables.ToList();
var query = (from prdtbl in products 
where prdtbl.cntrlIDs.Split(',').Any(x=> arrSearchFilter.Contains(x))
```

This is not a good idea if the Product table is large, as you are losing a key benefit of SQL and loading ALL the data before filtering.

#### Redesign

If that is a problem and you *can* change the database structure, you should create a child table that replaces the comma-separated values with a proper normalised structure. Comma separated variables might look like a convenient shortcut but they are not a good design and as you have found, are not easy to work with in SQL.

#### SQL

If the design cannot be changed and the table is large, then your only other option is to hand-roll the SQL and execute this directly, but this would lose some of the benefits of having Linq.